# Porque não consigo comentar perguntas aqui no SO?

Tags: suporte, comentários, reputação

Tem mais de mês que criei meu cadastro e até hoje não consigo fazer comentários nas perguntas, me deparo com diversas perguntas parecidas com problemas que tenho, porém pede alguns pontos de reputação.
Como consigo isso?

Comment: Comece fazendo o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como as coisas funcionam. Pode ler mais sobre reputação [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Você consegue pontos de reputação se ao fazer uma pergunta ou responder a uma pergunta a galera clicar na seta indicada pra cima ao lado da pergunta ou resposta. Se clicarem na seta para baixo você perde pontos de reputação.

Comment: Porque precisa de 50 pontos de reputação para comentar em qualquer lugar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado pelos links, ficou mais claro

Answer (score -5):

Você ganha pontos por cada resposta com voto positivo na plataforma, e ganha badges:

- A cada novo tipo de iteração (a primeira vez que comenta, a primeira vez que vota...)

Alguns badges são pré-requisitos para outros.

Algumas formas de "evoluir" na plataforma:

- Votando em respostas dos outros
- Respondendo
- Comentando
- Recebendo votos sob sua resposta

É um estilo de gamification em que quanto mais conteúdo de qualidade você provê, maior é seu ranking e isso te dá permissão a fazer mais coisas.

Comment: Esta resposta está errada. Dessas opções só ganhas pontos de reputação recebendo votos **positivos** sob a tua resposta. Também recebes pontos recebendo votos positivos em perguntas.

Comment: E também comentar não gera reputação, por mais que ela seja votada

Comment: Acho que a edição piorou um pouco. A pergunta fala sobre ganhar reputação, e a maior parte da resposta fala de como obter medalhas.